# How can I add a custom method to auth_user model class? I need to return a calculated field along with results

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, extend

I want to be able to write something like:

```
#extend user model with this method
def get_manager():
    #call some api to get the manager
    return user_manager
```

and to be able to display this in the template, like:

```
{{ user.get_manager }}
```

Please note that manager here is not the class manager. Actually my users are employees and I need to return the manager of each employee with the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [extend the django user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user).

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    def get_manager():
        ...
```

and in your template you can write

```
{{ user.employee.get_manager }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your user class is 'User'. To return its default manager, call:

```
User._default_manager
```

Comment: Thanks Iborgav. but I didn't mean the class manager. I should have clarified this. Manager here is an employee manager (or could be any other info that needs to be retrieved)